# ASP.NET - WebMethod not getting called when using Class, jsonerror

Tags: asp.net, json

I am trying to pass an object to a WebMethod which takes parameters as a class.
If I pass the parameters separately, it works, but not as a class. What am I missing?

My ajax call:

```
           var obj = {Id: 1234};
           var item = JSON.stringify(obj);

            $.ajax({
                url: 'InventoryItems.aspx/Update',
                data: item,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function () {
                    console.log("in success");
                }
            })
```

WebMethod:
The version that **works**:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Public Shared Function Update(Id As string) As String
    Dim res As String = ""       
    Return res
End Function
```

WebMethod:
The version that **does not** work:

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
Public Shared Function Update(item As Item) As String
    Dim res As String = ""       
    Return res
End Function
```

The class Item:

```
Public Class Item
    Public Property Id As String = String.Empty
End Class
```

I get a 500 error in Google Chrome dev tool. So, in gist, the WebMethod does not get hit if I put a breakpoint there. If I use just the Id as the parameter in the WebMethod, it gets hit. My original object has about 20 properties, so I would like to pass an object with 20 fields rather than passing 20 parameters separately.

Am I missing anything? Any reference or settings?

Thank you for helping me in advance.

Comment: Why are you using a WebMethod? Have you considered utilizing ASP.NET Web API instead?

Comment: No, but it is bizarre to me why it will not work this way. Shouldn't it work?

Comment: Try using method parameter instead of type so method: ‘POST’ and also set data to obj directly instead of stringify

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used WebMethod (which is basically deprecated). I don't recall it having the ability to automatically hydrate a complex item. You could have it accept a string, then manually convert the string to an object via a JSON library.

Comment: @mason, if I put anything other than explicitly using the parameter names, it does not work. I tried using item as string in the WebMethod, no, does not work.

Comment: @Mohsin Mehmood, tried them both and also separately just now, still the same error.

Comment: I think Id is string so obj should be {“Id”:1234”}

Comment: Put Id in quotes. Remove the content type and go with the default. Also see mason's comment above: "have it accept a string, then manually convert the string to an object via a JSON library." You can't pass in an object. Noop. Json.Net library (by Newtonsoft) will convert it for you. This way you can pass in all the props you want.

Comment: @wazz, if I do those, it is sending the entire page as data, showing SyntaxError in Google Chrome as "Unexpected token < in JSON at position 4",  and still not hitting the WebMethod.

Comment: Do you have `EnablePageMethods="true"` in the script manager? (and i guess you don't need the quotes if you stringify. [?])

Comment: Dbl-checked, you don't need the quotes if you stringify. Try default 'type' `GET`.

Comment: Fwiw, I've been fooling around with this in a recent website, .net 4.6 and i'm getting all the same problems you are. Never happened before. I checked in an older 4.0 website and everything works without a problem. Biggest differences i see right now b/t the two are, in the new website, there's a script manager on the *master* page, instead of individual pages as needed; and there is script bundling - probably the real culprit. Something is probably missing or not being loaded in the right order.

Comment: @wazz, thanks much for verifying. Assures me that I am not crazy.

Comment: It is really messed up.

Comment: Are friendly urls enabled?

Comment: @wazz there's nothing in here regarding framework versions or url. the JSON was not compliant to the expected object type

Comment: you might be right. the comment above "it is sending the entire page as data" led me to the friendly urls problem. the **page** method above that doesn't work will never be able to accept a class/type, it must take a string (or stringified object). IOW, `item as Item` is the problem; it should just be `item`). wonder if that will help. [It was mentioned already in the 4th and 8th comments above.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following worked for me:

The ajax call:

```
       var obj = {Id: 1234};
       var item = JSON.stringify(obj);

        $.ajax({
            url: 'InventoryItems.aspx/Update',
            data: JSON.stringify({item:item}),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function () {
                console.log("in success");
            }
        })

<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)>
   Public Shared Function Update(item As string) As String
   Dim res As String = ""     
   Return res
End Function
```

And then in that WebMethod, I could do something like:

```
    Dim jss As New JavaScriptSerializer()
    Dim itemDetails As Item = jss.Deserialize(Of Item)(item)
    dim id as string = itemDetails.Id
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem on my end is FriendlyUrls.

There's probably a better way to do this, but I excluded it from the project in the bin folder; and commented-out references to it in RouteConfig.cs and  ViewSwitcher.ascx. (You may have others.)

This was just for testing, but the problems I was having are gone on this page. I also have a script manager on my test-page, and the script manager and bundling are commented-out on the master page, but now I'm not convinced that that's an issue.

I guess the ASP.NET AJAX proxy class `PageMethods` looks for a complete url to find the code-behind method and bombs without it.

Comment: I put the script manager back on the master page and re-added the script bundling and the problem is still fixed. Seems to be friendly urls.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using input parameter as integer, its working fine as your JSON is compliant with the parameter

For parameter as an object, use following

```
{ "item": { "Id": "1234" } }
```

If the underlying Id property is a number, remove the corresponding quotes on 1234.

Note that the parameter name are case sensitive and hence "item" should have *i* in lower case and "Id" has in upper case. 
You follow the convention of :-

1. Opening and closing braces marks the boundary of field
2. Variable name has to be 1st ('item' in this case)
3. Variable value follows after a colon (an object with property "Id' and its corresponding value

2) & 3) gets repeated for the whole hierarchy of the concerned object.

Comment: Getting 401 (Unauthorized) error on Google Chrome. Tried passing as both raw and stringified objects, same error both times. Still the WebMethod not getting hit.

Comment: that's from the friendly urls issue.

Comment: So it changed from 500 to 401? That means you are authorizing the web method call and so. Need to pass appropriate token. The token and type of passing depends on the type of auth in place